# How to make running total ignore other columns DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table in `Power BI` that calculates the running total. However, when I add additional columns to the table, the values get messed up. Any ideas on how get the running total to ignore specific columns?

Here is my code:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Append1[AVAILABLE] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Append1[DUE DATE] ),
        Append1[DUE DATE] <> MAX ( Append1[DUE DATE] )
    )
)
    + CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Append1[ORDER QTY] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Append1[DUE DATE] ),
            Append1[DUE DATE] <= MAX ( Append1[DUE DATE] )
        )
    )
    - CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Append1[REQUIREMENT QTY] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Append1[DUE DATE] ),
            Append1[DUE DATE] <= MAX ( Append1[DUE DATE] )
        )
    )
```

Below are pictures of what the table looks like when it runs correctly and what it looks like when I add another column and the values get messed up.

Correct running total:

[image]

Incorrect Running Total:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use ALLEXCEPT to selectively ignore any but the selected filter context

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the syntax correct. Can you give me an example of how it should be written if I want to ignore the ID column in the above example?

Comment: And to be clear you don't mean using `SUMX` which ignores all filters, right?

Comment: What's going on in that first part of your measure... Append1[DUE DATE] <> MAX ( Append1[DUE DATE] ) ... do you really want it like that?  I would expect a "<="  not a "<>"

Comment: @Sky for performance purposes (1), bear in mind that "<" and ">" are complex operations that are translated into a sequence of comparison IN (val1, val2, ...). If your calendar goes from 2020 to 1900, using "<" would generate A LOT of comparison based on the cardinality of the field. Therefore, you might want to define it as NOT(Append1[DUE DATE] > MAX ( Append1[DUE DATE] )

Comment: @sky for performance purposes, (2) considering the filter applied **seems** (please confirm) to be always the same, you could simply define in the back-end (not as a calculated column but in the data source) a new data column which is the sum of (AVAILABLE, ORDER QTY, REQUIREMENT QTY). Then your measure will aggregate only that new data column.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working correctly using ALLSELECTED. Thanks for your help.